# AnonymousUser when logged with SimpleJWT

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I know it's not the first question of that kind, but other topics didn't help me.
I want to use djangorestframework-simplejwt to authenticate user and everything is fine since it comes to getting user. I always get AnonymousUser.

I obtain token by visiting api/token and passing credentials. Token is created correctly, it contains right user id. When I try to get access to protected view it allows me to, but Django doesn't recognise user.

**settings.py**

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "djmoney",
    "bills",
    "accounts",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",

]

ROOT_URLCONF = "shared_bills.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ]
        },
    }
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "shared_bills.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
    }
}


# Authentication

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator"
    },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator"},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

APPEND_SLASH = True


# CORS

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


# Rest Framework

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer"],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTTokenUserAuthentication"
    ],
}

if DEBUG:
    REST_FRAMEWORK["DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES"].append(
        "rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer"
    )
    REST_FRAMEWORK["DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES"].extend(
        [
            "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
            "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
        ]
    )


# Simple JWT

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(weeks=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': os.environ["SECRET_KEY"],
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

**views.py**
    """Views for accounts application."""

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.mixins import CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet

from accounts.models import User
from accounts.serializers import (
    PasswordCheckSerializer,
    UserChangePasswordSerializer,
    UserSerializer,
)


class IsAnonymous(BasePermission):
    """Allows access only to anonymous users."""

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return not bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)


class UserViewset(GenericViewSet, CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin):
    """Viewset for User object."""

    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "register":
            return UserSerializer
        if self.action == "change_password":
            return UserChangePasswordSerializer
        if self.action == "delete_user":
            return PasswordCheckSerializer

        return UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return get_user(self.request)

    @action(detail=True, methods=["post"], permission_classes=[IsAnonymous])
    def register(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Registering new User."""
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    @action(detail=True, methods=["post"], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def change_password(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Changes password."""
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(user, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response({"detail": "password changed"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @action(detail=True, methods=["post"], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def delete_user(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Deletes user."""
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(user, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user.delete()
        return Response({"detail": "user deleted"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I believe it's something obvious, couse I started learning drf few days ago but hours of searching google did not helped.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail your last sentence? "When I try to get access to protected view it allows me to, but Django doesn't recognise user". Which view? What do you mean by "Django doesn't recognise user"? Where in the code you're showing is that happening?

Comment: A UserViewSet doesn't returning anything. Depending on which method you call a view function is run, and it returns a JsonResponse. None of the actions you show "return email and id of logged user". Please be specific. What url are you calling (for which action: register, change_password or delete_user)? And if there's an error, what's the error trace?

Comment: @dirkgroten Sure. UserViewset should return email and id of logged user. Instead it returns error: _Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `AnonymousUser` instance.
Original exception text was: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'._.

Comment: So this is for the `retrieve` action?

Comment: try `return self.request.user` instead of `get_user(self.request)` in `get_object()`.

Comment: Yes. To be more specific: UserViewset url: api/user allows only get method. This is what we're talking about. Register action url api/user/register allows access only for non logged user and it works fine. Delete action throw error: _Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser._.

Comment: Something changed. Instead of AnonymousUser it returns TokenUser: _AttributeError at /api/user/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `TokenUser` instance.
Original exception text was: 'TokenUser' object has no attribute 'email'._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should use `self.request.user` instead of `get_user`. The latter assumes session-based authentication and is a function used by the session auth backend to add the user to the request object. Regardless of the auth backend, the middleware takes care of fetching the user for you and adds it to the request object.

Also you’re using `JWTTokenUserAuthentication` instead of `JWTAuthentication`. The latter would return you a `User` object in your request, whereas the former puts a `TokenUser` in the request.

See [this explanation](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/blob/master/README.rst#experimental-features).

Comment: Thank you! At first I used JWTAuthentication, but changed it in hope it will fix something. Anyway thank you very much!